# LESS selector for descendant or self

Tags: less

Given two selectors e.g. "Div.aClass"  and ".sub" is there a shorthand in LESS that would mean:

```
Div.aClass .sub, Div.aClass.sub
```

i.e. any element that has a `sub` class but is also either a `Div` with `aClass`  or a child of such a div ?

I suppose I can use:

```
Div.aClass {
  &.sub, & .sub {

  }
}
```

but a shorter syntax would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really do not have much shorter of a syntax available. The most you can eliminate is one `&`:

```
Div.aClass {
  &.sub, .sub {
    prop: test;
  }
}
```

Comment: :( I was expecting some clever LESS syntax like `Div.aClass;.sub` or something like this... maybe I should suggest it somewhere...

Comment: I know this specific syntax is not that good but something along those lines... maybe introducing a `?` as an indicator that the previous char is optional `Div.aClass ?.sub` so `Div.aClass>?.sub` would mean  that a .sub that is also a Div with aClass or has such a Div with aClass as its direct parent.

Comment: This usage case is probably too rare to warrant a special selector like that for LESS, especially when the syntax already is not that verbose. But you can certainly suggest it. I may be wrong :-).